# Is SO reputation mechanism patented?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Can a system similar to SO reputation be implemented on another website, or it is covered by patents or other restrictions?

I may be interested in replicating the following features:

- Users have a reputation.
- Reputation is increased by up votes and decreased by down votes.
- Privileges like voting, editing, closing are earned by reaching levels of reputation.
- Deleting posts restores reputation.

I'm asking this because I think that this system is great and helped building a quality self moderating community which I find very difficult to achieve. If I want to build a community around an hypothetical future website, It may be worth implementing such rules.

Comment: I'm quite sure there's lots of prior-art, even if that would have been patentable at some prior time, the way the patent-offices work today...

Comment: even if you make same mechanism you wont able to get that much of post stackoverflow has and without content there is no use of that website

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there are no patents, and you are free to re-implement the same ideas. The ideas for Stack Overflow came from other systems, [such as XBox 360 achievements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/), they were not specifically new or novel.

There are plenty of software packages available that re-implement the Stack Overflow model, see *[Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones)* over on Meta Stack Exchange.